# Are the verify methods in java.security.cert.Certificate thread-safe?

Tags: java, security, thread-safety

In general, can the verify-methods in [java.security.cert.Certificate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/security/cert/Certificate.html) be considered thread-safe? Specifically, [verify(PublicKey key)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/security/cert/Certificate.html#verify%28java.security.PublicKey%29) and [verify(PublicKey key, String sigProvider)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/security/cert/Certificate.html#verify%28java.security.PublicKey,%20java.lang.String%29). Can multiple threads call these methods simultaneously without worrying that they will modify internal data in a thread-unsafe way?

The JavaDoc does not mention anything about this. Perhaps this is implementation specific?

I would like to do something like this:

```
Certificate certificate = getCertificateFromCache();
certificate.verify(whatever);
```

Ideally without putting it in a synchronized block.

Comment: What's your actual concern? `verify` shouldn't change the certificate so calling the same method on the same certificate from simultaneously shouldn't cause problems !?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking: are the methods thread safe? Are there any guarantees that the calls do not modify internal data in a thread-unsafe way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Certificate.verify` is an abstract method. So from this perspective there can't be any guarantee, that all implementations are always thread-safe. Maybe the documentation of the actual certificate implementation tells you something about it, but, to be safe, you may have to synchronize the call to verify on the actual certificate.

Maybe you can create something like a pool of equal certificate instances to bypass that problem. Then you could verify in parallel on different instances of the same certificate.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Can't see any reason for it not to be thread safe, but it's impossible to know for sure without knowing how it's implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [`sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl` source](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/x509/X509CertImpl.java), it has some `synchronized` methods (including `verify`) and a `private ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> fingerprints` field.

So it seems to me that there was a clear intent to make it thread-safe.

Unfortunately `synchronized` methods updating inner state fields like `verificationResult`, `verifiedPublicKey`, `verifiedProvider` would incur some performance overhead during concurrent access from many threads.

It may be more efficient to avoid `synchronized` locks contention by caching instances in `ThreadLocal`, for example.